# How to get human-body detection distance using camera (Lidar Scanner)

Tags: ios, swift

how can I get human-body (people) distance detection?
I want get people distance and direction from camera.
I used ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, LidarScanner, BodyTrackingConfiguration but proper solution not found

Comment: I don't think that is possible due to the limited range the sensor can provide. which is 5 meters.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.